# Trying to make a function that returns selected CSS properties but is pretty laggy

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I was trying to make a function that gives you the selected CSS properties of an element those you want. But it's pretty laggy if used in console as of it needs to get and match all CSS properties.

```js
function styleOf(elementUseSelectors, propertiesToCheck, tellInConsole) {
  var element = elementUseSelectors;
  var Arguments = propertiesToCheck;
  var calculatedProperties = [];
  var matchedProperties = [];
  if (tellInConsole !== undefined && tellInConsole == true) {
    console.warn("Running styleOf() Please Don't Do Other Calculations This Function Disables Console.")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(getComputedStyle(element)).length; i++) {
    var value = getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(Object.entries(getComputedStyle(element))[i][0].replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim().replaceAll(" ", "-").toLowerCase());
    if (value !== "") {
      calculatedProperties.push(Object.entries(getComputedStyle(element))[i][0].replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim().replaceAll(" ", "-").toLowerCase() + ": " + value);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < calculatedProperties.length; i++) {
    for (var a = 0; a < Arguments.length; a++) {
      if (calculatedProperties[i].includes(Arguments[a])) {
        window.splitted = calculatedProperties[i].split("");
        window.joinThis = [];
        for (var k = 0; k < splitted.indexOf(":"); k++) {
          joinThis.push(splitted[k]);
        };
        if (joinThis.join("") == Arguments[a]) {
          matchedProperties.push(calculatedProperties[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (tellInConsole !== undefined && tellInConsole == true) {
    console.warn("StyleOf() Calculations Completed You Can Now Use Console.")
  }
  return matchedProperties
}
```

Comment: I'd look into using the `TreeWalker` object – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker

Comment: I am a beginner so I don't know a lot about these things. Slowly becoming an intermediate. By trying to code random things.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your code... Do you just pass the Element as the first argument and an Array containing the rules you want in the second and want the computed values of these rules for the element? In that case that's just `function styleOf(element, properties) { const computed = getComputedStyle(element); return properties.map( key => computed[ key ]); }`

Comment: @kaiido yeah that's what I want thanks :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) object is designed to quickly parse DOM nodes in a document. If you expand on the example given above in the MDN Web Docs you can output the computed CSS properties for a given node.

The first property of the method is the node you want to traverse – in this case it's `document.body`:

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
  { acceptNode: function(node) { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; } },
  false
);

var nodeList = [];
var currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;

while(currentNode) {
  nodeList.push(currentNode);
  const style = getComputedStyle(currentNode)
  console.log(style)
  currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
  console.log("moving to next node...");
}
```

Comment: This gives the CSS of every element inside the body element. And takes longer. I know we can select the element we need the style of but....

Comment: Yep that's an extreme example, the computed style for every single element in a complicated website can be an expensive operation. Give it a try it with a more specific selector though. You could also look at Web Workers if you're going to be outputting this stuff to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Welp @kaiido answered the question.

```
function styleOf(element, properties) { 
const computed = getComputedStyle(element); 
return properties.map( key => key + ": "  +  computed[ key ] )};

var style = styleOf(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], ["height", "width", "background-color", "font-size", "color", "font-family"]);

console.log(style);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).